# How to include Boost.DLL into C++ code?

Tags: c++, boost, dll, include

I am trying to complete the Boost.DLL tutorial (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html)

However, I'm not able to even compile their source code, I keep getting:

```
fatal error: boost/dll/import.hpp: No such file or director
```

I tried manually copying the header files from the repository (https://github.com/apolukhin/Boost.DLL), but even when I copy these into "/usr/include/boost/" I get new errors from the same kind about "boost/predef/os.h".

I've tried reinstalling the complete boost library and everything, but without success.

Since they describe themselves as "Boost.DLL is a header only library. To start with the library you only need to include  header"
It seems like there should be an easier way to fix this than go through the include-errors and manually search for the right files on the internet...

Comment: the link you provide to the `Boost.DLL` tutorial is to a development version of `boost` - it isn't a part of the current (1.60.0) release. So you'll have to download and build the development version to complete the tutorial.

Comment: @kenba Thanks for the information. I downloaded the 1.61 beta version and it works like a charm